# Form and means of japanese reduplication

Tags: meaning, reduplication

Im on my research about form and meaning of japanese reduplication. Have you guys ever heard or use 休み休み? What exactly the meaning is? If I translate 'resting multiple times' is it right? 
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like young girl who is in high spirits due to 休み.

Comment: So is it like someone has a cheerful personality or what?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already know onomatopoeia/mimetic words such as キラキラ and ヒューヒュー, which heavily use reduplication. The following is only about duplicated *verbs*.

There are a few words that appear in the form of "repeated verbs", but you have to memorize their meanings one by one, looking them up in a dictionary:

- [休み休み](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BC%91%E3%81%BF%E4%BC%91%E3%81%BF) (no-adj): "resting at times; with pauses"

  - There is an idiomatic phrase [バカも休み休み言え](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/174685/meaning/m0u/) ("don't talk stupid", "go and boil your head").
- [ノリノリ](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B9%97%E3%82%8A%E4%B9%97%E3%82%8A) (no-adj): "in high spirits​; cooking" (almost always written in kana)
- [イケイケ](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91) (na-adj/no-adj): "excited; upbeat" (almost always written in kana)
- [飛び飛び](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B3%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B3) (no-adj): "with intervals; scattered; sporadic"
- [泣く泣く](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B3%A3%E3%81%8F%E6%B3%A3%E3%81%8F) (adverb): "tearfully; with great regret; reluctantly"
- [返す返す](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%BF%94%E3%81%99%E8%BF%94%E3%81%99) (adverb): "indeed; really; repeatedly"

Basically you cannot repeat arbitrary verbs (aside from rare exceptions in poetry/lyrics, where verb reduplication is occasionally employed for metrical purposes, e.g., 「本を読み読み」 = "reading a book").

You can use [`V + に + V` pattern to express doing something intensively and/or repeatedly](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24851/5010). This is a generic pattern with which you can use almost any verb.

Comment: Is V+に+V pattern use for reduplicated verbs? Does reduplicated verbs in Japanese just as you've mention above? Mm if I translate 休み休み as 'resting multiple times while do something' am I right?

Comment: @user25631 1) See the link. You can say 走りに走った, 笑いに笑った and so on and on. 2) Maybe correct, but I can't tell without seeing the full sentence.

Comment: Mm but almost in data that Ive found the pattern for reduplicated verbs are not like that...most of all V+V pattern without に. Ex : 恐る恐る 泣き泣き 代わる代わる... Hmm Im just see the meaning based on derived word not from the sentence..Is it hard to decide if I just look the meaning from the derived word?

Comment: 恐る恐る and 代わる代わる are adverbs listed in a dictionary, and they have their own (unpredictable) meanings. You have to memorize the meaning of each
word. 恐れに恐れる is not listed in a dictionary, but it simply means "to be extremely afraid." It's a generic pattern you can reuse with many various verbs once you've understood it.

Comment: But before become adverbs, both of are verbs right?

Comment: Of course. What's your point?

Comment: I still dont get it...so in other words reduplicated verbs are very  limited? We cant reduplicated those verbs willingly?

Comment: @user25631 Right, that's why they are listed in dictionaries as distinct adverbs, no-adjectives, etc. (I'm talking about ones without に, of course) Didn't I say "there are a few words" and "you cannot repeat arbitrary verbs"? Here's the [entry for 休み休み](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/221901/meaning/m0u/) in a monolingual dictionary; it says 休み休み is an established adverb.

Comment: Mmm okay...I think I got it...btw is it valid for search the reduplicated words meaning using japanese web dictionary such as kotobank.jp, weblio.jp, ejje.weblio.jp and dictionary.goo.ne.jp?

Comment: Sure. [折り折り means "sometimes"](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/33838/meaning/m0u/), but probably you cannot tell its meaning without a dictionary.

Comment: Okeeyy.... Thanks a lot for your answers 